# Where does Sugar Cube: Bittersweet Factory save game progress?

Tags: sugar-cube

In what location on the file system does Sugar Cube: Bittersweet Factory store your progress when you save in game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Steam, the game uses Steam Cloud. The save weights 36 bytes.

As for the DRM-free version of the game, the answer is still unknown.

Comment: Steam cloud just backs up files.  They must already exist on your hard-drive somewhere.  This is not an answer.

Comment: The question was not about the location of Steam Cloud backups. This is off-topic.